# how can I parse date time in pandas with a specific format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a direct CSV stream from an API that I am using to push data into a database with the following code:

```
def loadData(data, engine) :
stream = data.content

try:
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(stream.decode('utf-8')))
    df['Snapshot'] = datetime.datetime.now()

    if file.split(".")[0] == "SIM_SDS" :
        df.to_sql(file.split(".")[0], engine, if_exists='append', index=False, infer_datetime_format = True)
    else :
        df.to_sql(file.split(".")[0], engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, infer_datetime_format = True)
except:
    print('Loading data to the database failed for ' + file)
```

The problem I am having is the datetime format that is coming in is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ (EG. 2017-10-30T20:26:22.731Z)

I have found a lot of different versions where there is just a T or a T with a +0300, but I have yet to find this particular format and I can't seem to get it to parse these as datetimes.  The other piece of this challenge is that the datetime fields aren't the same in every single case, so I also have to have a way of recognizing this format as a datetime.

The problem this creates is when it creates the table in the database since the fields are shown as text; this leads to issues when these are used in tableau for datediff type work.

Try 1:

```
dateCol = [col for col in df.columns if 'Date' in col]
    for col in dateCol:
        df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: x.strip('T').strip('Z'))
        print(df[col])
```

This failed, I think because of the NaN issue where there is no date in the field.

Comment: There is another monkey in here: sometimes the dates are NULL (EG. NaN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with the following:

```
def loadData(data, engine) :
    stream = data.content

try:
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(stream.decode('utf-8')))
    df['Snapshot'] = datetime.datetime.now()
    df.where(df.notnull(),None)
    dateCol = [col for col in df.columns if 'Date' in col]
    for col in dateCol:
        df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

    if file.split(".")[0] == "SIM_SDS" :
        df.to_sql(file.split(".")[0], engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    else :
        df.to_sql(file.split(".")[0], engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
except:
    print('Loading data to the database failed for ' + file)
```

This results in the proper format of the table fields I know for sure should be datetimes being datetimes.

Feel free to give me suggestions to improve though.